# Bootstrap 2 responsive images

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have inherited a website where bootstrap 2 mark up is being used but the images have a html width set like so:

```
<img src="text.jpg" alt="blog" width="525" height="379">
```

So when this page is reduced down to tablet view the images break through the column/grid structure and are not being resized.

Is there a class or something I can use to make these images responsive?

Many thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the following styles to the images:

```
img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%; // Set a maximum relative to the parent
  height: auto;    // Scale the height according to the width, otherwise you get stretching
}
```

Or create an .img-responsive class and add to the images:

```
.img-responsive {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%; // Set a maximum relative to the parent
  height: auto;    // Scale the height according to the width, otherwise you get stretching
}
```

This also works without removing the width and height:

```
<img src="text.jpg" alt="blog" width="525" height="379" class="img-responsive">
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just realized that these images had a css style that was overriding bootstrap.

So they were picking up this:

```
max-width:520px;
```

Instead of bootstraps:

```
max-width:100%;
```

It had nothing to do with the inline style as I first thought.

Comment: I wrote you same answer half hour ago. :)

Answer (score -1):

Remove `width="525" height="379"` and try to put % values. That is the problem here.